# Cordova update and lost craftyjs' tween and gravity

Tags: android, cordova, craftyjs

I'm trying to update a mobile Cordova game to the following versions:

/**
 * craftyjs 0.7.0
 * http://craftyjs.com/

Cordova:

{ name: 'cordova',
  description: 'Cordova command line interface tool',
  'dist-tags': 
   { latest: '6.0.0',

I lost .gravity() and .tween()

I checked Craftyjs documentation and my code looks ok:

```
Crafty.e("phaser")
    .attr({
             x: (this.x+18),
             y: this.y,
             w: 8,
             h: 12
           })
             .tween({alpha: 0.0, x: (this.x+18), y: -1},1250);
           });
```

and:

```
Crafty.e("blaster")
    .attr({
             x: der,
             y: 10,
             w: 8,
             h: 12
           })
             .gravityConst(0.04)
             .gravity("floor");
```

Any hints?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Cordova integration, but you are calling methods that haven't yet been added to your entities.
Adding the respective [`Tween`](http://craftyjs.com/api/Tween.html) & [`Gravity`](http://craftyjs.com/api/Gravity.html) components to your entities should solve the issue:

```
Crafty.e("2D, Tween, phaser")...
Crafty.e("2D, Gravity, blaster")...
```

Comment: Thanks! I already declared the objects in another file named components.js:  Crafty.c('blaster', {
                        init: function() {
                                this.requires('Actor, Color, Solid, Gravity, Collision, Tween')

Comment: Crafty.c('Actor', {
      init: function() {
        this.requires('2D, DOM');
      },
    });

Comment: @FNode So does that resolve the issue or does it still not work in Cordova?

Comment: It solves the gravity issue, I´m having issues with scene and tween but it seems a collision issue thanks!